# File reading all lines at once

Tags: php

I'm working on a small script to help me copy files from one directory to another. I'm using input from a .txt file with a few hundred lines to tell the script where to copy the files from. For some reason, instead of reading and editing lines in the file one by one, it seems to be running once through the entire file, and adding all of the values together.

Example: echo on $from_location will read:

```
http://localhost:8888/copy_images/media_catalog/products/0/6/06-2821.jpg /media_catalog/products/1/1/11-1256.jpg /media_catalog/products/1/1/11-1258.jpg /media_catalog/products/1/1/11-1260.jpg
```

instead of what it should read which is:

http://localhost:8888/copy_images/media_catalog/products/0/6/06-2821.jpg 
http://localhost:8888/copy_images/media_catalog/products/1/1/11-1256.jpg http://localhost:8888/copy_images/media_catalog/products/1/1/11-1258.jpg http://localhost:8888/copy_images/media_catalog/products/1/1/11-1260.jpg

Please see the script here:

```
$handle = fopen("images.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        $from_location = 'http://localhost:8888/copy_images' . $line;
        $create_location = str_replace('media_catalog','catalog',$line);
        $to_location = 'http://localhost:8888/copy_images' . $create_location;
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 
?>
```

I'd love to learn what I'm doing wrong so I can improve my php moving forward!

- Nick

Comment: Could be an issue with the line endings in your .txt file.

Comment: In your example, it looks like on the first iteration `echo $from_location` prints `$line` with the `'http://localhost:8888/copy_images'` part that you've added, and then on all the subsequent iterations it just prints `$line`? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing your result through `HTML` so there's no line-break until you add `<br>` tag.

It's printing correctly:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("images.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
    while ( ($line = fgets($handle)) !== false ) {
        $from_location = 'http://localhost:8888/copy_images' . $line;
        $create_location = str_replace('media_catalog','catalog',$line);
        $to_location = 'http://localhost:8888/copy_images' . $create_location;

        echo $line . '<br>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

**Or** to ignore `HTML` rendering, you can just add `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` right after `<?php`. So you don't need to add `<br>` at the end of `echo`.

Cheers.

Comment: The issue still persists even after the line break

Comment: @NicklK Have you tried `header("Content-Type: text/plain");`? It's working for me.